# Error while running juju deploy jenkins-slave

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins, provisioning, juju

Note: I'm running this on 3 Ubuntu trusty VM's on my OS X laptop over VMWare Fusion.

I am a juju newbie and having some trouble with setting up jenkins-slave.  I have a bootstrap machine, and 2 other machines.  Jenkins (master) is successfully installed on machine 1.  When I try to deploy jenkins-salve I get the error message:

```
juju deploy -n 1 jenkins-slave
cannot assign unit "jenkins-slave/0" to new machine: use "juju add-machine ssh:[user@]<host>" to provision machines
```

I also tried:

```
juju remove-service jenkins-slave
juju deploy jenkins-slave --to 2
Added charm "cs:precise/jenkins-slave-7" to the environment.
ERROR cannot assign unit "jenkins-slave/0" to machine 2: series does not match
```

It makes no sense, since before attempting to deploy jenkins, I added two machines:

```
juju add-machine ssh:machine1
juju add-machine ssh:machine2
```

both successfully finished.  Here's my status output

```
juju status
environment: manual
machines:
"0":
agent-state: started
agent-version: 1.20.14
dns-name: thebat
instance-id: 'manual:'
series: trusty
hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=979M
state-server-member-status: has-vote
"1":
agent-state: started
agent-version: 1.20.14
dns-name: elemental
instance-id: manual:elemental
series: trusty
hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=979M
"2":
agent-state: started
agent-version: 1.20.14
dns-name: terrifying
instance-id: manual:terrifying
series: trusty
hardware: arch=amd64 cpu-cores=1 mem=979M
services:
jenkins:
charm: cs:trusty/jenkins-2
exposed: false
units:
  jenkins/0:
    agent-state: started
    agent-version: 1.20.14
    machine: "1"
    open-ports:
    - 8080/tcp
    public-address: elemental
jenkins-slave:
charm: cs:precise/jenkins-slave-7
exposed: false
units:
  jenkins-slave/0:
    agent-state: pending
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is quite simple, yet very unlikely.  The charm for jenkins-slave is a precise charm, which means it can *only* be installed on a precise Ubuntu VM.

While this only seems obvious after an entire day with juju, I believe it is a major problem with this tool.  Chef / Puppet, etc are not flavor dependent, so why is juju flavor version dependent.  It's a major lack of planning in my opinion.